# Getting a users discord about me with discord.py

Tags: python, api, discord, discord.py

From my understanding there is zero official documentation on getting a user's about me but I have seen it done. Does anyone know a work around?

Comment: I do not think it's possible as requesting `GET users/{id}/profile` (the endpoint used for getting the profile in the Discord client) returns 403 Forbidden with adding "Bots cannot use this endpoint"

Answer (score 0):

Since version 1.7 you can only get the user profile when running a non-bot account. So, you really can't no more without breaking discord rules. [Here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.User.profile) you can see that mentioned.